# Copy a range of values based on date in another column

Tags: vba, excel, date, for-loop

I am trying to write a macro that copies a range of values in one column based on the corresponding date in another column.

For example, I need to copy the values in column G that correspond to the date in column B.  For 9/18/2015 I need to select and copy the range in column G based on the date 9/18/2015 from column B.  Then I need to do the same thing for 9/19 and so on for all other dates.  I am then pasting it to several other pages, although that portion of the code is not included here.

My attempt below only checks the date in column B and then copies a range in column G.  I believe I need a for loop but I am not sure how to build it correctly for what I need.

```
 If ActiveCell >= Date + 1 And ActiveCell <= Date + 7 Then

' Compare date on Day Sheet to sheet s and select cells in column G
' corresponding to that date

        x = ActiveCell
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("s").Activate
        Range("B2").Select

' If statement to check if dates match

            If ActiveCell = x Then
            Range("G2").Select
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Select
            Range("G2:G10").Copy
            Else
            End If
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the situation, but it sounds suspiciously like some `VLookup` formulas on your destination tabs could do this without VBA. Is there a particular reason you can't use those instead?

Comment: That could possibly do it but it's more complicated than that.  I will also need the code to check the text in the next column (C) to determine which cell it will go in on the sheet for the particular date it corresponds to.  For example, there will be a range of cells corresponding to tomorrow 9/18.  Once that range has been identified, I will need the code to then identify the text in column C and match it to other text on another sheet to determine where to paste the value.

Comment: I'm having a tough time visualizing what we are trying to accomplish. Can you tell us a little more about the way your data is structured?  Is column B a bunch of dates you are trying to loop through to test whether they are between tomorrow and a week from today?  It looks like you set `x` equal to `ActiveCell` but then right after that you test to see whether `ActiveCell` equals `x`. It seems like that would evaluate to true 100% of the time.  Can you explain in step-by-step order what you are trying to have it do?

Comment: Sure, let me explain what I am looking at first so you can better understand that and then I can explain the steps I am trying to take.  I download a spreadsheet daily from a database that has dates grouped together in column B, account names in column C, and amounts in column F.  I create a formula in column G to take a % of column F.  There are between 9-12 accounts corresponding to each date in column B so there will be several rows that are for 9/18 and then several rows for 9/19 and so on.

Comment: I have 36 other sheets labeled Day 1 - Day 36 and some of them will have dates that match the dates from the downloaded sheet.  On each one of those sheets, there is a column with all the account names and the column next to that is where I want to paste the value for the corresponding date and account name from the downloaded sheet.  I need to do that for each date and each account name.  Right now I am stuck on the dates and the next step will be the account names.

Comment: Step 1 is to check the dates in column B and copy all the values that correspond to that same date in column G and then paste them on the corresponding Day sheet(I already have a loop that does this portion).

Comment: Step 2 would be to then integrate checking the account names and pasting to the correct cells corresponding to the account name but I haven't wanted to go that far until I get the date portion to work.  I will try to post a screen shot of the sheets.  That would make it easier to visualize.

Comment: It won't allow me to post an image.  I need to have at least 10 reputation points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh this is spooky. I have a practically identical task right now - except mine is a monthly flight log imported from SQL to Excel that has to transfer the daily hours to pilots' personal worksheets. Switch 'account' to 'pilot' and 'amounts' to 'flight time' and our projects are absolutely the same.

I've practically just cut and pasted my code below and it will do the whole shabang for you. It's not great form on StackOverflow to solve someone's entire task for them, but in this case it seems pointless only pasting a bit of the procedure.

The big lesson for me was to treat Excel only as the data retrieval and data display interface. The trick is to create your own data structures, read the data into them, manipulate/interrogate them as required, then write results to the worksheets when everything's done. In other words, avoid the macro generator like the plague! I rather suspect your copy cell x,y paste to cell r,c approach will take you to the same dead-ends I went up. The best way I found was to have a `Dictionary` of pilots (accounts for you) and then an inner `Dictionary` of flight dates (value/dates for you). You then simply test for an account key and a date key for each account of your Day sheets.

To access the `Dictionary` object you need to reference `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` (Tools -> References... -> select in list by ticking check box).

You'll need to create two classes - these are your data fields. Call the first `cAccountFields` and add the following code to the class:

```
Public AccountName As String
Public ActivityByDate As Dictionary
Public Sub Create(accName As String)
    Me.AccountName = accName
    Set Me.ActivityByDate = New Dictionary
End Sub
```

Call the second `cActivityFields` and add the following code to the class:

```
Public DateOf As Date
Public Value As Double
Public Sub Create(dat As Date, val As Double)
    Me.DateOf = dat
    Me.Value = val
End Sub
```

Then just add the following code to your module. The private constants need to be declared at module level (ie at top of page). You can use these to define your row and column references - it really would be uncanny if they matched the pilots' logs:

```
Private Const DB_SHEET As String = "Sheet1"
Private Const DB_DATE_COL As String = "B"
Private Const DB_ACCOUNT_COL As String = "C"
Private Const DB_VALUE_COL As String = "G"
Private Const DB_ACCOUNT_START_ROW As Long = 1
Private Const DAY_DATE_ADDRESS As String = "A1"
Private Const DAY_ACCOUNT_COL As String = "A"
Private Const DAY_VALUE_COL As String = "B"
Private Const DAY_ACCOUNT_START_ROW As Long = 2


Public Sub ProcessData()
    Dim daySheets As Collection
    Dim accountsFromDB As Dictionary
    Dim account As cAccountFields
    Dim activity As cActivityFields
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim dat As Date
    Dim accName As String
    Dim accValue As Double
    Dim endRow As Long
    Dim r As Long

    ' Create a Collection of the Day sheets
    Set daySheets = New Collection
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Left(ws.Name, 4) = "Day " Then
            daySheets.Add ws
        End If
    Next

    ' Read the database sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(DB_SHEET)
    Set accountsFromDB = New Dictionary

    endRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                           After:=ws.Range("A1"), _
                           LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                           LookAt:=xlPart, _
                           SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                           SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    For r = DB_ACCOUNT_START_ROW To endRow

        dat = ws.Cells(r, DB_DATE_COL).Value2
        accName = ws.Cells(r, DB_ACCOUNT_COL).Text
        accValue = ws.Cells(r, DB_VALUE_COL).Value2

        ' Add the account or retrieve it if it already exists.
        If Not accountsFromDB.Exists(accName) Then
            Set account = New cAccountFields
            account.Create accName
            accountsFromDB.Add key:=accName, Item:=account
        Else
            Set account = accountsFromDB.Item(accName)
        End If

        ' Add the value for a specific date.
        If Not account.ActivityByDate.Exists(dat) Then
            Set activity = New cActivityFields
            activity.Create dat, accValue
            account.ActivityByDate.Add key:=dat, Item:=activity
        Else
            ' If the same account and date occurs, then aggregate the values.
            Set activity = account.ActivityByDate(dat)
            activity.Value = activity.Value + accValue
        End If

    Next

    ' Populate the Day sheets
    For Each ws In daySheets

        dat = ws.Range(DAY_DATE_ADDRESS).Value2

        endRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                               After:=ws.Range("A1"), _
                               LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                               LookAt:=xlPart, _
                               SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                               SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

        For r = DAY_ACCOUNT_START_ROW To endRow

            accName = ws.Cells(r, DAY_ACCOUNT_COL).Text

            ' If account and value for this date exists then write the value
            If accountsFromDB.Exists(accName) Then
                Set account = accountsFromDB.Item(accName)
                If account.ActivityByDate.Exists(dat) Then
                    Set activity = account.ActivityByDate.Item(dat)
                    ws.Cells(r, DAY_VALUE_COL).Value = activity.Value
                End If
            End If

        Next

    Next

End Sub
```

**Updated after OPs Q's:**

Add additional constants at module level and amend as appropriate:

```
Private Const DB_BOOK As String = "Macro Test File.xlsx"
Private Const DAY_BOOK As String = "Macro Test File.xlsx"
Private Const INITIAL_SHEET As String = "Initial Revenue"
Private Const INITIAL_COL As String = "E"
```

Then use this code:

```
Dim daySheets As Collection
Dim accountsFromDB As Dictionary
Dim account As cAccountFields
Dim activity As cActivityFields
Dim dbWb As Workbook
Dim dayWb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim dat As Date
Dim accName As String
Dim accValue As Double
Dim endRow As Long
Dim r As Long

' Assign the workbook containing the database sheet
On Error Resume Next
Set dbWb = Workbooks(DB_BOOK)
On Error GoTo 0
If dbWb Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Please open " & DB_BOOK & " in this application and run this routine again."
    End
End If

' Assign the workbook containing the days sheets
On Error Resume Next
Set dayWb = Workbooks(DAY_BOOK)
On Error GoTo 0
If dayWb Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Please open " & DAY_BOOK & " in this application and run this routine again."
    End
End If


' Create a Collection of the Day sheets
Set daySheets = New Collection
For Each ws In dayWb.Worksheets
    If Left(ws.Name, 4) = "Day " Then
        daySheets.Add ws
    End If
Next

' Read the database sheet
Set ws = dbWb.Worksheets(DB_SHEET)
Set accountsFromDB = New Dictionary

endRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                       After:=ws.Range("A1"), _
                       LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                       LookAt:=xlPart, _
                       SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                       SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

For r = DB_ACCOUNT_START_ROW To endRow

    dat = ws.Cells(r, DB_DATE_COL).Value2
    accName = ws.Cells(r, DB_ACCOUNT_COL).Text
    accValue = ws.Cells(r, DB_VALUE_COL).Value2

    ' Add the account or retrieve it if it already exists.
    If Not accountsFromDB.Exists(accName) Then
        Set account = New cAccountFields
        account.Create accName
        accountsFromDB.Add Key:=accName, Item:=account
    Else
        Set account = accountsFromDB.Item(accName)
    End If

    ' Add the value for a specific date.
    If Not account.ActivityByDate.Exists(dat) Then
        Set activity = New cActivityFields
        activity.Create dat, accValue
        account.ActivityByDate.Add Key:=dat, Item:=activity
    Else
        ' If the same account and date occurs, then aggregate the values.
        Set activity = account.ActivityByDate(dat)
        activity.Value = activity.Value + accValue
    End If

Next

' Populate the Day sheets
For Each ws In daySheets

    dat = ws.Range(DAY_DATE_ADDRESS).Value2

    endRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                           After:=ws.Range("A1"), _
                           LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                           LookAt:=xlPart, _
                           SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                           SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    For r = DAY_ACCOUNT_START_ROW To endRow

        ' Write the standard formula into the cell
        ws.Cells(r, DAY_VALUE_COL).Formula = "='" & INITIAL_SHEET & "'!" & _
                                             INITIAL_COL & CStr(r)

        accName = ws.Cells(r, DAY_ACCOUNT_COL).Text

        ' If account and value for this date exists then write the value
        If accountsFromDB.Exists(accName) Then
            Set account = accountsFromDB.Item(accName)
            If account.ActivityByDate.Exists(dat) Then
                Set activity = account.ActivityByDate.Item(dat)
                ws.Cells(r, DAY_VALUE_COL).Formula = ws.Cells(r, DAY_VALUE_COL).Formula & _
                                                     " + " & CStr(activity.Value)
            End If
        End If

    Next

Next
```

Comment: I haven't used classes before so I'm not familiar with them.  I've looked online a little bit but I am having trouble setting them up.  What do I need to do to set up a class correctly?

Comment: They're pretty straight forward. You're basically creating your own object that has methods and properties like any other object. In your code, for example, `ActiveWorkbook` is an instance of an object and `Sheets` is one its properties. To set up a class, on your menu bar, click Insert -> Class Module. At the bottom left of the editor in the Properties Window, you can type its `Name`. Default is `Class1`. On the right is where you enter the code, just like any Module.

Comment: Thanks for the help with the classes.  That was a very simple thing.  I'm now getting the error "Object variable or With block variable not set" and it points me to the endRow section of the code when I click debug.

Comment: Sounds as if there's a problem with the Worksheet object. Check (at top of module) that you have assigned the constant `DB_SHEET` the name for your worksheet. If that's correct, put the following line in your code, run it and tell me what it said. `Debug.Print "ws Is Nothing = " & (ws Is Nothing) & ". Sheet is " & ActiveSheet.Name`. The output will be at the bottom of your editor in the Immediate window.

Comment: You were right, that name was incorrect.  I corrected it and now its telling me the subscript is out of range at set ws.

Comment: `DB_SHEET` must be a string. It sounds as if you've assigned an integer. Even if your sheet name is a number it must be in inverted commas, eg "1".

Comment: I have DB_SHEET at the top as a string with the correct name in that format and it still gives me that error.

Comment: Subscript out of range error means Excel can't find the sheet. Either the name is still wrong or the worksheet isn't in the same workbook that your VBA is written in. Activate the worksheet and paste the following in your Immediate window (bottom of editor): `? ActiveSheet.Parent.Name & " " & ActiveSheet.Name` and hit enter. Paste back here the output from that and the `DB_SHEET` line in your code.

Comment: Now I'm back to the previous issue.  Where in the code should I put Debug.Print "ws Is Nothing = " & (ws Is Nothing) & ". Sheet is " & ActiveSheet.Name.  I can't get it to give me an output.

Comment: Hi. It doesn't go in your code, it goes in something called the `Immediate Window`. By default, that window is visible in your editor at the very bottom of the window. If it isn't then click View -> Immediate Window. You just paste the code in there and hit return. The output will also be displayed there. Note, it's very important that this worksheet we can't find is the active sheet (ie you've just clicked on it) before you paste the code. Also the code you want to copy is this: `? ActiveSheet.Parent.Name & " " & ActiveSheet.Name`

Comment: Ok, so that gave me the sheet name that I was on and that all looks to be correct now.  Now I am getting the Object Variable error again.  Before you gave me the Debug.Print to put in the code.  Where in the code do I want to put that?

Comment: I put it in the immediate window and it returned the following:  ws Is Nothing = False. Sheet is Sheet1

Comment: Sheet1 is the name of DB_SHEET

Comment: Okay, so now put in the immediate window this: `? ThisWorkbook.Name & " " & ActiveSheet.Parent.Name`. Please paste the results here and paste the DB_SHEET line here.

Comment: PERSONAL.XLSB Macro Test File.xlsx

Comment: Private Const DB_SHEET As String = "Sheet1"

Comment: Excellent. Here's your problem: you're running your VBA from `PERSONAL.XLSB` and your worksheet is on a different file, ie `Macro Test File.xlsx`. It's an easy fix and I'll put an edited version of the code in my answer. Can you let me know which file holds your "Day n" sheets.

Comment: The Macro Test File holds the Day sheets.  The real file will have a different name once I get this one working so I'm glad we found this issue.

Comment: Wow! It worked!  That is absolutely amazing, thank you so much for your help!  One last thing I need to add while we are on the topic.  Some of the days will already have a value in a cell in column B because I update this file daily and I need to do two things.  I need to clear out any values and replace them with the current values, but I need it to not replace any links and simply add the new value to that link.  Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: That's good. Yes, the link thing is very easy - just one extra line of code. Give me an example of one of your links and how you want the cell to look once the value is appended, eg. separated by a space, comma, etc.

Comment: The link is simple.  I just create a formula in each of the cells and in some of them I add a value from another sheet at the end of the workbook.  So I just need to have it clear out any number values in all cells and just add to anything linked to another sheet. So the link would just be something like ='Initial Revenue'!E32+...  Sometimes there will two of those in the same cell.  I want to have to value added in the formula.  If possible, I'd like to have all of the others create formulas as well in case I need to add anything else to them.

Comment: I'd also like to put values into another sheet but based only on the corresponding date and I want them to sum all the values for each date.  Could I use the current classes and dictionaries to set that up?

Comment: I have a few other tweaks I'd like to do after that, but I'm confident I can do those on my own.

Comment: See my edited post for changes. It's untested so you may have to play with it a bit.

Comment: That seems to have changed everything and it's not doing what it was before. I need it to just clear out the value that's already in each cell and replace it with the current value.  The easiest way to deal with the link issue is to just check the cell for text or for a sheet reference and not clear that portion on the cell, then clear any value, and then use the special operation add to add the value from the DB_SHEET.

Comment: It's trying to reference the Initial Revenue sheet.  I don't need it to reference a different sheet, I need it to not delete a sheet reference if there is one in a cell.  I need it to clear all the values from the cells and then put the value from the DB_SHEET into each of the cells but add the value to a cell that already has a formula and a sheet reference in it.

Comment: Tom, this is too big to answer here. Post a new question. I'm not really sure what you're trying to do, so, in your new question, make sure you give actual examples of what's in the cells, of what you want to keep and what you want to delete. Be sure to try something yourself first, of course, otherwise people will downvote your question.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing actually.  I'll post a new question after I give it a shot myself.  What do I need to change to get it back to where it was when it was first working?  I can work with that code in the meantime.